# How to create batch file to run my code igniter function from window task schedules

Tags: codeigniter-2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YBZd.png)I'm trying to schedule my codeigniter function from window task scheduler my code igniter file structure is "`C:\wamp\www\tas\application\controllers\my_controller\my_function"` , I prepared my batch file like this

```
php C:\wamp\www\tas\application\controllers my_controller my_function
```

but it is not working.

My codeigniter version is 2.2

Comment: Hello! Please, define what "not working" is. Did you get any errors by running this command? Which was the error?

Comment: i'm not getting any error, but i'm not getting the result the function is expected to do. when i run the function through browser i'm getting the result that means my controller's function is correct i presumed the issue is on my .bat file definition or i've missed some setups in my codeigniter or windows OS.

Comment: do you think my .bat file definition is correct  i.e. php C:\wamp\www\tas\application\controllers my_controller my_function

Comment: If you managed to run your code without throwing errors, there is no problem with the batch file. The batch file works like command prompt... Mind sharing your code, or any snippets related to the issue?